# Red to green progress bar using GTK3 and Python

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

So here I'm trying to make a progress bar that is red at 0%, and its color gradually changes until green at 100%, but I have no idea anymore how to do it.

I tried accomplishing it by recoloring the built-in gtk.ProgressBar through a CssProvider, but the underlying css styles are so messy that I couldn't get it to work -- not to mention I couldn't manage to mix the colors as desired either.

I considered drawing my own widget from scratch using cairo, but I couldn't find any guides on the net on how to do so.

At the moment I'm trying to get this work under Ubuntu, but a platform independent solution would definitely be better.

**Edit** eventually I solved it with the code below. It's a workaround using gtk.Table. The background of the bar is not colored (I tried, but couldn't give the table itself a background color). The progress part is colored with a top-down gradient of the color and has 3px rounded corners. Though this version is still static-only, a [slightly modified version](http://blog.valerauko.net/2014/01/18/gtk3-red-to-green-progress-bar-in-python/) I made can be dynamic (with limitations).

```
class mybar(gtk.Table):

    def __init__(self, total, now, label):

        super(mybar, self).__init__(1, total, True)
        self.set_size_request(150,5) ## just set a size for it
        self.show()

        self.id = 'mybar'+str(id(self)) ## unique id for the css
        self.set_name(self.id)

        self.set_tooltip_text(u'%s: %d/%d' % (label, now, total)) ## Label: current/max

        bar = gtk.Label()
        bar.show()

        p = now/float(total)
        m = 0.7 ## this makes the colors darker, 1 for full brightness 0 for black
        if p < 0.5:
            r = m
            g = p*2*m
        elif p > 0.5:
            r = (1-p)*2*m
            g = m
        else:
            r = m
            g = m
        color = gdk.RGBA(r,g,0,1)

        ##print color.to_string() ## uncomment this to print the current color rgb to terminal

        css = gtk.CssProvider()
        css.load_from_data('''
@define-color barcolor %s;
#%s GtkLabel {
    font:6px;
    background:-gtk-gradient (linear, center top, center bottom, from (shade (@barcolor, 1.05)), color-stop (0.5, @barcolor), to (shade (@barcolor, 0.95)));
    border-radius:3px;
}
''' % (color.to_string(), self.id) )

        bar.get_style_context().add_provider(css, gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION )

        self.attach(bar, 0, now, 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try having a look at how to draw a cairo surface onto a gtk widget here: http://www.tortall.net/mu/wiki/PyGTKCairoTutorial

Maybe you could use that with your existing code!